# Install dev tools extension in vscode extension development host

Tags: electron, google-chrome-devtools, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a vscode webview extension that uses React. I debug the webview code by running my extension in the vscode extension development host and then opening dev tools on the development host window, from here I can inspect the webview.

How can I install a dev tools extension (React dev tools) inside the extension development host?